# tf.keras & tf.estimator & tf.dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to update my code to work with TF 2.0. as a start, I have used a pre-made keras model:

```
def train_input_fn(batch_size=1):
  """An input function for training"""
  print("train_input_fn: start function")

  train_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(CSV_PATH_TRAIN, batch_size=batch_size,label_name='label',
                                                        select_columns=["sample","label"])
  print('train_input_fn: finished make_csv_dataset')
  train_dataset = train_dataset.map(parse_features_vector)
  print("train_input_fn: finished the map with pars_features_vector")
  train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat().batch(batch_size)
  print("train_input_fn: finished batch size. train_dataset is %s ", train_dataset)
  return train_dataset

IMG_SHAPE = (160,160,3)
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                              include_top = False,
                                              weights = 'imagenet')

base_model.trainable = False
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001),
             loss='binary_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])

estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model = model, model_dir = './date')

# train_input_fn read a CSV of images, resize them and returns dataset batch
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=20)

# eval_input_fn read a CSV of images, resize them and returns dataset batch of one sample
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(eval_input_fn)

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec=train_spec, eval_spec=eval_spec)
```

LOGS are:

```
train_input_fn: finished batch size. train_dataset is %s  <BatchDataset shapes: ({mobilenetv2_1.00_160_input: (None, 1, 160, 160, 3)}, (None, 1)), types: ({mobilenetv2_1.00_160_input: tf.float32}, tf.int32)>
```

ERROR:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer Conv1_pad is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: [None, 1, 160, 160, 3]
```

What will be the right way to combine tf.keras with dataset API. is this the issue or something else?

Thanks,
eilalan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need this line

```
  train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat().batch(batch_size)
```

Function you're using to create dataset, `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset` alredy batched it. You can use `repeat` though